# How To Download PDF File From Google Drive with WebView

Tags: java, android, pdf

I want to download a file from my drive link.
I don't know how to do it and what's the code.
The URL is https://drive.google.com/open?id=1txJFXxL9uY3AjyQ3C2G9t9lSkhJqaxuO.
When I try this code, my WebView go freezing.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wvnpwpop);

    //Webview
    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.wvnpwpop);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1txJFXxL9uY3AjyQ3C2G9t9lSkhJqaxuO");
    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request( Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myPDFfile.pdf");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
    //WebSettings
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    // -------- End Of WebView and Web Settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check:

```
 webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(mUrl));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: I try but the result still same, webView still freezing not showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to login. Find url to login and redirect to your gdrive distination